# Detecting touch of a masked portion of sprite (as opposed to hidden portion), swift, spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What is the correct approach to limiting touch detection to just the masked area of an image sprite?

The code below is (in theory) how I hoped it would work.  It is a large colored block, masked with the shape of a spaceship.  When the user touches, I want only the masked portion to respond to touch.  In the below code, the events are ignored (probably since cropNode.maskNode is a property, not a child).  I've tried other approaches, but none limit touch to just the masked area.

Question is.. how is this *supposed* to be done?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let cropNode = SKCropNode();
    let mostlyHiddenSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSize(width: 300,height: 300))
    cropNode.addChild(mostlyHiddenSprite)
    cropNode.maskNode = TouchableMask(texture: spaceShipTexture, color: nil, size: mostlyHiddenSprite.size)
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: 400, y: 200)
    self.addChild(cropNode)
    println("try to touch the masked portion");
}

class TouchableMask: SKSpriteNode {
    override init (texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor?, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.zPosition = 999
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("Mask was touched.");
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Frank

Comment: Could you post the code you have used to create the SKCropNode?

Comment: @ZeMoon I've added a code block and updated the explanation. Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I was stuck with the myself. I solved it by doing this.

```
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)


            if(mask.contains(location))
            {
               //this will work only if the touch is in the mask.
            }
     }}
```